# Send email with Codeigniter but note see in mail box

Tags: codeigniter, email

I am using CodeIgniter to send email and use CPanel. And here is my code in email.php file in application/library folder and set email to auto load.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'localhost';
$config['smtp_port'] = '25';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'info@mydomain.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'mypassword';
$config['validation'] = TRUE;
```

And below is code when I send email.

```
$this->email->from('noreply@mydomain.com', 'mydomain.com');
$this->email->to($rescue_email);
$this->email->bcc('support@mydomain.com');
$this->email->subject('mydomain- Request a new password');
$this->email->message($message);            
$this->email->send();
```

I don't know why it cann't send?. Before it send correctly.

When I use,

```
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

It's display,

```
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: sendmail
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Wed, 20 Feb 2013 08:31:42 +0100
From: "mydomain.com" 
Return-Path: 
To: recipient@email.com
Bcc: support@mydomain.com
Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?mydomain_-_Request_a_new_password?=
Reply-To: "noreply@mydomain.com" 
X-Sender: noreply@mydomain.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <51247bdee59ff@mydomain.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
```

email send successfully. I check in mailbox nothing i can see, but in spambox.

Comment: u mean to say that the mail is coming in Junk/Spam folder instead of Inbox???

Comment: from what I understand the mail was going to the inbox earlier, but now it is not. Instead it is going to the spam folder. If this is the case then the main problem is that the domain name is blacklisted and hence the mails are going to spam. Once easy way is sending through SSL and Gmail credentils, but for that you have to check if the support is present with the shared hosting that you are using.